# Trigonometric system of 4 modular equations after Ramanujan

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, modular-forms

The system is the following:

$\sqrt{\sin w \sin x}+\sqrt{\cos w\cos x}=1\tag1$

$\sqrt{\sin v\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x\cos v}=4^{1/3}\big(\sin v\sin x\cos v\cos x\big)^{1/12}\tag2$

$\big(\sin u\sin x\big)^{1/4}-\big(\cos u\cos x\big)^{1/4}=\big(\sin v\sin w\big)^{1/4}-\big(\cos v\cos w\big)^{1/4}\tag3$

$\big(\sin u\sin v\sin w\sin x\big)^{1/4}+\big(\cos u\cos v\cos w\cos 
x\big)^{1/4}+\big(\sin 2u\sin 2v\sin 2w\sin 2x\big)^{1/12}=1\tag4$

The system of 4 equation above has many solutions, but
One of the most beautiful solutions is:

$\sin u=(2-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}})^{2}(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5})$
$\sin v=(2+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}})^{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})$
$\sin w=(2+\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}})^{2}(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5})$
$\sin x=(2-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2}(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}})^{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})$

Many others exist! And the best....?

Another solution:

$\sin{u}=(Abc)^{2}d$

$\sin{v}=(aBc)^{2}D$

$\sin{w}=(aBC)^{2}d$

$\sin{x}=(ABC)^{2}D$

$$Aa=Bb=Cc=Dd=1$$

$$a=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$b=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$$

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$d=\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}$$

Another solution, very simple, is the following:

$\sin x=\cos u=\frac{-\sqrt{30}+3\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{16}$

$\sin u=\cos x=\frac{+\sqrt{30}+3\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{16}$

$\sin v=\cos w=\frac{+\sqrt{30}+3\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{16}$

$\sin w=\cos v=\frac{-\sqrt{30}+3\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{16}$

Comment: Looking at the equations it is found that $\sin v, \sin w, \sin x$ are of degree $3,5,15$ respectively over $\sin u$.

Comment: Yes! You're right! Very well, you are on the right track!
Soon, I'm going to publish another solution

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way how do you evaluate those values of elliptic moduli? Do you use some algorithm or some math software?

Comment: No software! Only the values of gn and Gn of Ramanujan.

Comment: That's Ramanujan style via hand, pen and paper. Waiting for your posts dealing with such topics.